# Want to show similar view from resolution 1680 to 980 without increasing or decreasing any single pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My client want to keep same view of page from resolution 1680 to 980. Is it possible to keep same view on all resolution without increasing a single pixel or with out increasing the size of image.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: try to give fix width

Comment: But Height of pixels never be same on different resolutions. and if we keep same width than what we will do for fonts. In resolution 1680, fonts seems very small and images looks small but on resolution 980 and other resolutions ( smaller than 1680) its look big compare to resolution 1680. I want every thing looks same as per resolution 1680.

Comment: instead of considering (1680-980) as a single media query devide it into more media query like (1200-980) and (1680-1200). So it will help you to adjust font-size and image.

Comment: We can not keep different different media queries because we don't know at what resolutions client will see it... may be he will look more than 1680. 1680 is just an example.

Comment: after 1680 try to give  max-widtth to whole container. Otherwise I don't think there is any option

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is your friend, I would resize the image and have two image files one for mobile widths and one for Laptop, or Desktop widths. The most common problem is that the image size compresses to fit the width of the smaller screen when it does that the height drops to keep the image ratio. When you resize the image I would query the image.

```
<img class="img1" src="desktop-img.jpg"/>
<img class="img2" src="mobile-img.jpg"/>
```

then css query

```
.img1 {
display:block;
width:100%;
}
.img2 {
display:none;
}
/* ipad landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

.img1 {
display:none;
}
.img2 {
display:block;
width:100%;
}
     }
```

you might add or change your queries ex.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width://what ever size you want) 
and (max-device-width://what ever size you want)
```